# How to add a Scala expression to another to create a link in Play?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

How to add a Scala variable in the following line:

```
<a href=@routes.Application.routeToPage("@labels.get('lang')", "about_us")>About</a>
```

`labels` is a `Map`.

However when I click the link I get `http://0.0.0.0:9000/@labels.get('lang')/about_us` - note `@labels.get` inside.

**UPDATE**

When I try to do as comments suggest I get `illegal start of simple expression`.

```
<a href=@routes.Application.routeToPage(@labels.get("lang"), "about_us")>About</a>
```

With single brackets I get `unclosed character literal`

**FIXED**

This is the right way:

```
<a href=@(routes.Application.routeToPage(labels.get("lang"), "about_us"))>Abouts</a>
```

Comment: Play's templating system is *Scala inspired* at best, but not Scala. As for the problem itself, remove the double quotes, so `<a href=@routes.Application.routeToPage(@labels.get('lang'), "about_us")>About</a>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is quoting something you want evaluated as a variable:

```
<a href=@routes.Application.routeToPage(labels.get('lang'), "about_us")>About</a>
```

`@` introduces a Scala expression. And it's evaluated as such in its entirety. So no need for `@` before `labels`.